# how to use setResizable method here

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, jcomponent

[image]
I am using netbeans as an IDE. how can i set `setResizable(false)` on JFrame.I dont see the object of JFrame in netbeans.

Comment: just call `setResizable(false);`

Comment: 1) Paste code (with proper formatting) here, screenshots are useless. 2) Learn to use the import keyword... 3) We are missing a bit of context here (what do you do with all thee components?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've extended JFrame, the easiest way is in the Properties window - there is a property "resizable" in "Other Properties" where you can just untick the box.

Or, in the Source view you will have a constructor - put it there. e.g. if your class name is MyFrame

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form MyFrame */
    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setResizable(false); // insert this line
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `setResizable(false);` in non static methods of the class. 
From the image

> setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.ExIT_ON_CLOSE);

It is a clear indication that you have already extends the `JFrame` class.

Comment: on whose object? where has the netbeans constructed JFrame object.??

Comment: @Meprogrammer do you extend `JFrame` ?

Comment: @Meprogrammer: the instance of the class in the image.

Comment: @Meprogrammer are you built your GUI by using Java Desktop Aplication

Answer (score 1):

Generally we entend JFrame to create a Frame.

- Check in your code if it extends , then just call setResizable(false);

Comment: In many cases Extending a JFrame is not good design.  Either way calling `setResizable(false);` is correct.